# How to correct this conditional tag?

Tags: html, blogger

i have this conditional tag but written incorrectly and I want the appropriate form for it

```
<b:if cond='data:widget.sectionClass == &quot;sidedHome&quot;'></b:if>
```

The error lies here

> sectionClass

and Thanks <3

`

Comment: Hi MSDesCUC. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit confusing. What is the context of your conditional tag? What are you trying to achieve? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default `widget` object has four keys `id`, `type`, `title`, `sectionId`, since <s>sectionClass</s> not listed you can use `sectionId` instead to filter.

Comment: omg are you Muhammad Saleh owner a template Levon and Squezee .. I am a big fan of your business, I am also from Egypt. I have contacted you on Facebook about something and wait for your response .. Thank you for the solution, my friend.

Comment: Thanks bro .. what's your account name on fb ?

Comment: this link : [my page](https://www.facebook.com/HamoGemey1) my name Mohamed Gamal